# php strpos not working while searching <br /><br /> after nl2br()

Tags: php, strpos

I'm having trouble using `strpos` correctly. if I search for`<br />` it will find it. If I search for `<br /><br /><br />` with or without space between, it won't and using `htmlspecialchars` I can tell the string is full of it.

```
   <?php
   $picArray = glob('projectData/' . $data['folder'] . '/*.jpg',GLOB_BRACE);

    $text = nl2br($data['definition']).'<br />';

    $cutP = 0;
    foreach($picArray AS $insert) {

        if(strpos($text,'<br /> <br /> <br />',$cutP) !== FALSE){
            $cutP = strpos($text,'<br /> <br /> <br />',$cutP)+6;
            echo $cutP.'_';
            $str_to_insert = '<img class="inTextImg" title="int" src="'.$insert.'" />';
            $text = substr($text, 0, $cutP) . $str_to_insert . substr($text, $cutP);
        }
        else {
            echo 'haha';
            $text .= '<img class="inTextImg" title="outText!" src="'.$insert.'" />';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Thank your for your ideas.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $text;`?

Comment: Maybe what you think is `<` actually is `&lt;`?

Comment: Could you break down this problem to a simple script? Without any references to your fodler structure etc. Just give an example of when it fails. Generally speaking it's better to use Regular Expressions for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Bondye: echo $text echo exactly the text with the <br /> being interpreted by the browser correctly. ficuscr: unfortunatly no it is not &lt; Lukasz well to go to to core strpos will find <br /> but not <br/><br/> even if it is 100% sure it's in $text.  I'll try regular but i need the position of the found string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `nl2br` keeps the original line break characters in place, just after the `'<br />'`. You need to include the line break characters in the string to search for. Since there can be a few different patterns for this it's easiest to use a regexp to match it:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?:<br \/>\r?\n?){3}/', $str_to_insert, $text);
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why `strpos` fails to match against the string.

Comment: Thanks I need to keep the <br /> in place so I did $text = str_replace("\n",'',$text);
$text = str_replace("\r",'',$text);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using preg_match() ?

```
if(preg_match("\(<br />)+\",$text) > 0){
    // code
}
```

Not 100% on the regex, but you would want one that checks for one or more br tags